# asp:LinkButton - validate form field

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms, validation

I am completely new to C# and I am trying to figure out form validation.
More specifically, I have a webform (C#) that I've split into to parts "form-part-1" and "form-part-2".

By default "form-part-2" is hidden. Once all fields in "form-part-1" are completed, you should be able to proceed to "form-part-2" by clicking on the "Continue" linkButton.

The jQuery part works well, showing and hiding form sections as desired.
But the validation is not enforced anymore.

I have validators in place but at this point I can proceed to "form-part-2" without filling out the "form-part-1" fields.

I would like the validation to be enforced before proceeding to "form-part-2".

Any tips and suggestions how to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#continue").click(function (event) {
                $('#form-part-1').hide();
                $('#form-part-2').fadeIn();
            });

    });

</script>

<form id="SignUp" method="post" runat="server">

<table id="validation">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" vAlign="top">
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsSignupValidation" runat="server"></asp:ValidationSummary></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="form-part-2">
<tr>
    <td width="150">
            <label class="">
            <asp:label id="lblSignupFirstName" Runat="server">First Name:</asp:label>
            <span style="color:red">*</span>
            </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox size="30" CssClass="input" ID="txtSignupFirstName" TabIndex="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="150">
            <label class="">
            <asp:label id="lblSignupLastName" Runat="server">Last Name:</asp:label>
            <span style="color:red">*</span>
            </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox size="30" CssClass="input" ID="txtSignupLastName" TabIndex="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- validate and continue -->
    <asp:LinkButton ID="continue" runat="server"  onclientclick="return false;">Continue</asp:LinkButton>
<!-- validate and continue -->

<table id="form-part-1">
<tr>
    <td width="150">
            <label class="">
            <asp:label id="lblSignupUserID" Runat="server">UserID:</asp:label>
            <span style="color:red">*</span>
            </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox size="30" CssClass="input" ID="txtSignupUserID" TabIndex="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="150">
        <label class="">
            <asp:label id="lblSignupPassword" Runat="server">Last Name:</asp:label>
            <span style="color:red">*</span>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:TextBox size="30" CssClass="input" ID="txtSignupPassword" TabIndex="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="150">
        <label class="">
            <asp:Label class="formtxtsm" ID="lblSignupConfirmPassword" runat="server">Confirm password</asp:Label>
            <span style="color:red">*</span>
        </label></td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox size="30" ID="txtSignupConfirmPassword" TabIndex="10" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="input"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- validators -->
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvSignupFirstName" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtSignupFirstName" class="formerrortxt" ErrorMessage='"First Name" is required'></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvSignupLastName" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtSignupLastName" class="formerrortxt" ErrorMessage='"Last Name" is required'></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSignupUserID" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtSignupUserID" ErrorMessage='"Username" is required.'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvSignupPassword" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtSignupPassword" ErrorMessage='"Password" is required.'></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvSignupConfirmPassword" runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtSignupConfirmPassword" ErrorMessage='"Confirm password" is required.'></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
<asp:customvalidator id="cvSignupPasswordMatch" runat="server" Display="None" ErrorMessage='"Password" and "Confirm password" must match exactly.'></asp:customvalidator>
</form>
```

******** EDIT:

Thanks Phx & Daniel for your feedback. Very helpful! 
I got things working with one exception. The "form-part-2" fields get validated before I even get to the step 2. Any tips how to validate the username / password fields only after I get to the "form-part-2"? Thanks in advance!

here's my most recent version:
www.smithy.somee.com

and the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {            
    if (Page_ClientValidate("personalGroup")) {
        $('#form-part-1').hide();
        $('#form-part-2').fadeIn();
    }            
    if (Page_ClientValidate("accountGroup")) {                    
        $('#form-part-2').hide();
    }
});
</script>

    <form id="signup" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table id="validators">
            <tr>               
                <td>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="personalGroupSummary" runat="server" ValidationGroup="personalGroup" />
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="accountGroupSummary" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="accountGroup" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="form-part-1">
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>                       
                    <asp:Button ID="continue" runat="server" causesvalidation="true" validationgroup="personalGroup"  Text="Continue"  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <table id="form-part-2">
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>                                      
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" validationgroup="accountGroup" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- output -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First: </td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblFname" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblLname" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Pass:</td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblPass" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

        <!-- validators -->

            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="fvFname" runat="server" validationgroup="personalGroup" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtFname" ErrorMessage='"First Name" is required'></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="fvLname" runat="server" validationgroup="personalGroup"  Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtLname" ErrorMessage='"Last Name" is required'></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="fvUser" runat="server" validationgroup="accountGroup" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtUser" ErrorMessage='"Username" is required'></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
            <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="fvPass" runat="server" validationgroup="accountGroup" Display="None" ControlToValidate="txtPass" ErrorMessage='"Password" is required'></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

        <!-- validators -->
    </form>
```

Comment: its been long since I last used form validation with asp.net but it probably had something to do with client side validation, the validator had something  like `dynamic` or something that used to enable it validating client side, because since you are using jQuery, obviously you are using client navigation, and thus asp.net does not know to validate yet as the form is not posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote: *I would like the validation to be enforced before proceeding to "form-part-2"*.

You need to create validations groups in order to validate first N fields and the another N Fields.
So create Validation groups for your controls:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227424(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<asp:textbox id="AgeTextBox" 
      runat="Server">
    </asp:textbox>

<asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2"
      controltovalidate="AgeTextBox"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
      errormessage="Enter your age."
      runat="Server">
    </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>

<!--When Button1 is clicked, only validation
    controls that are a part of PersonalInfoGroup
    are validated.-->
    <asp:button id="Button1" 
      text="Validate" 
      causesvalidation="true"
      validationgroup="PersonalInfoGroup"
      runat="Server" />



<asp:textbox id="CityTextBox" 
      runat="Server">
    </asp:textbox>


    <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator3"
      controltovalidate="CityTextBox"
      validationgroup="LocationInfoGroup"
      errormessage="Enter a city name."
      runat="Server">
    </asp:requiredfieldvalidator>



    <!--When Button2 is clicked, only validation
    controls that are a part of LocationInfoGroup
    are validated.-->
    <asp:button id="Button2" 
      text="Validate" 
      causesvalidation="true"
      validationgroup="LocationInfoGroup"
      runat="Server" />
```

Then use a Diferent validation summary for each group.

Perhaps you need a button for each validation but you can do the trick and use the same button for multiple validation groups:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Validate-Multiple-Validation-Groups-with-one-Button-in-ASPNet.aspx

Another example here
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401611/Validate-multiple-Validation-group-both-client-and

Comment: This answer would be much better if you included some of the code from your first link. For example, the validatePage method which is absolutely essential.

Comment: Thanks so much for your guidance. Any idea how to get the user and password fields validation triggering only on the "form-part-2" of the form? Thank you!

Comment: Daniel Cook writes just the way to validate groups. Check his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Phx gives a partial answer. Use his suggestion to create ValidationGroups. Put all your validators in part 1 and part 2 in separate groups.

**JQuery does not automatically trigger validation.**

You need to call the validation manually with your JavaScript. This can be done by calling `Page_ClientValidate` which will validate all validators for the passed ValidationGroup.

For example:

```
$("#continue").click(function (event) {
   if (Page_ClientValidate("group1")) {
      $('#form-part-1').hide();
      $('#form-part-2').fadeIn();
   }
});
```